# QuickLook file associations

Tags: macos, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

Typing `$ qlmanage -m plugins` will give me a list of QuickLook plugins and their associated MIME type (at least I think it's a MIME type):

```
plugins:
  org.openxmlformats.presentationml.slideshow -> /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator (32)
  com.adobe.pdf -> /System/Library/QuickLook/PDF.qlgenerator (622.3)
  com.apple.localized-pdf-bundle -> /System/Library/QuickLook/LocPDF.qlgenerator (622.3)
  com.apple.iwork.keynote.key -> /Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator (11)
  ...
  public.script -> /Applications/Development/TextMate 2.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator (1.0 - loaded)public.source-code -> /Applications/Development/TextMate 2.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator (1.0 - loaded)
  public.plain-text -> /Applications/Development/TextMate 2.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator (1.0 - loaded)
  public.text -> /Applications/Development/TextMate 2.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator (1.0 - loaded)
  ...
```

Questions:

- What is the number in parentheses?
- How do I know which plugin will be used by a given file?  Is it just the file's extension or is MIME type (e.g. public.plain.text) embedded in the document's metadata?
- How do I get [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoc.org/) documents associated with one of the plugins that renders plain text?
- How do I change plugin associations?  For example, use Sublime Text's plugin instead of Text Mate's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you are looking for is contained in each Quick Look plug-in's `Info.plist` file. This file is embedded in the Quick Look plug-in bundle: `Contents/Info.plist`

The number in the parentheses is the bundle version (`CFBundleShortVersionString`). This should be a unique identifier for the developer to determine the exact build of the plug-in; compare this to a marketing version of `1.1`.

The [qlmanage manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/qlmanage.1.html) details how to see associations and the expanded help shows more options:

```
qlmanage -h
```

For details on how to add or change associated files, see [Apple's Quick Look developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/quicklook_programming_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). The associations are set out in the Info.plist file's `CFBundleDocumentTypes` section.

The MultiMarkdown Quick Look plug-in provides a useful [example of the Info.plist](https://github.com/ttscoff/MMD-QuickLook/blob/master/MultiMarkdown%20QuickLook/MultiMarkdown%20QuickLook-Info.plist) settings.