# QuickLook set app to display preview

Tags: xcode, preview, quicklook

Is it possible to set the app that displays the QuickLook preview in OS X?

I'm developing iOS apps and I have Xcode installed, but when I open the QuickLook preview of a Source-Code file, the preview uses the iA Writer, which I have also installed but the "Open with" button un the top right corner shows Xcode.

Info: I'm using a MacBook Air, Late 2010, OS X 10.9.2

[image: Ql with iA Writer]

If I uninstall iA Writer it looks like this

[image: no IA writer]

Question:

How do I tell the Quick Look NOT to use the iA Writer (without having to uninstall it)?

Comment: what is the question here? you want to change the open with? or something else?

Comment: The question is if it is possible to set the program used for the preview in QuickLook

Comment: So the QL correctly identifies the file and displays it using the QL plug in for it!, You do not like the display ? What does the iA write has to do with it? What app do you want to open with QL?

Comment: I want it not to use iA Writer for the preview. If I uninstall iA Writer, it looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ejo7ifvdvospqto/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2011.48.28.png

Comment: when you RIGHT click on the Open with, what options do you see ?

Comment: I see this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/clpszxhh1nkc92f/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2012.44.53.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### qlmanage

Use the command line tool [qlmanage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/qlmanage.1.html) to investigate your QuickLook set up, including the default generator for each file format.

> qlmanage -- Quick Look Server debug and management tool

Apple's [QuickLook developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/quicklook_programming_guide/articles/qldebugtest.html) documentation provides a good overview of how QuickLook works and how to test specific plugins.

#### Editing the iA Writer QuickLook Plugin

You may want to edit the iA Writer QuickLook plugin to disassociate it from your `.h` and `.m` files. See [QuickLook file associations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122509/quicklook-file-associations/122526#122526) for more information about achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is coming a lot later, but I had to figure this out for myself. Go to where Writer is located

1. Go to where Writer is located. /Applications/
2. Right click and show package contents
3. Enter Library
4. Delete QuickLook
5. Restart your computer or enter into command line qlmanage -r

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. select the file and press cmd+I.
2. Then under "Open with" select the application you want to open in QuickLook.
3. And then press the "Change All..." button

Comment: This only changes the application that opens the file when you doubleclick on it, it doesn't affect the QuickLook Plugin.

Comment: This does not change the quicklook, as asked. Furthermore, it changes the application that opens the extension, which was not asked for.